# Is it possible to have a multiple toogle function in a *ng for loop within a *ng for loop in Angular

Tags: angular, ngfor

Been stuck on this forever but I'm new to angular so want to make sure this is possible.

```
<!-- posts on messageboard -->

<div *ngFor="let messageboard of (this.messageboard || []); let i = index"><br>

    <h5> {{messageboard.title}} </h5><br>
    <li>{{messageboard.post}}</li>




<!-- ability to view comment on each post on messageboard -->

<button (click) = "seeComments(messageboard.postID); toggle[i] = !toggle[i]">View Comments</button><br>
<div *ngIf = "toggle[i]">
<div *ngFor="let comment of (this.comments || [])"><br>
 
<li> {{comment.commenter}}</li>
<li>{{comment.comment}} </li>

</div>
</div><br>


</div>
```

Toggle referenced in ts file:

```
toggle = {};
```

So once I click the 'View Comments' button the correct and corresponding comments are displayed underneath the correct post (I can also re-click this same instance of the button to close the toggle and collapse the comments).

However, the issue is that if I click the View Comments button and comments for a post toggle open, and then without closing this instance, I click view comment on the next post below, the new list of comments appear below it (which is fine) but they also duplicate on the previous post and all other instances of 'viewComments' that are currently toggled open.

Is it possible to make it so that once I click on view Comments under a post, any other instances of it instantly close while the new one opens?

Comment: If you only want a unique instance open at time, not use an array (really work, but you should declare the toggle variable as `toggle=[]`), just a simple variable "toogleSelect". You can use `(click)="toogleSelect=i"` and `*ngIf = "toogleSelect==i"`